# Component reference is undefined in nested React.createElement(...) call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm-install, package.json

I've had this code working for months without an issue, but after running npm install and thereby re-installing my node_modules, it has stopped working.

```
import { Footer } from 'components/common';

....

  public render() {
    return (
      <Provider {...this.stores}>
        <div className="app">
          {this.props.children}
          <Footer />
          <DevTools />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

becomes ...

```
_createClass(App, [{
    key: "render",
    value: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
            mobx_react_1.Provider,
            this.stores,
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "app" },
                this.props.children,
                React.createElement(common_1.Footer, null),
                React.createElement(mobx_react_devtools_1.default, null)
            )
        );
    }
}]);
```

common_1 is for some reason undefined and I can't figure out why.

mobx_react_1.Provider is not, so it seems like only nested components are affected. If I add "let myVariable = < Footer />" before return, then it's working as intended (even if I never reference myVariable in the return statement!)

I've tried different components but always get the same error. I'm not getting any compilation errors (beside "DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() ..") and I've not changed my webpack.config. These are the dependencies in my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.55",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "mobx": "3.1.2",
    "mobx-react": "4.1.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.30.7",
    "react-breadcrumbs": "1.5.2",
    "react-datetime": "2.8.6",
    "react-dnd": "2.1.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.1",
    "react-router": "3.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "0.23.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "0.14.57",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.23",
    "@types/react-router": "2.0.48",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
    "babel-core": "6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.22.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.26.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "3.3.0",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "4.2.11",
    "node-sass": "4.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "sass-loader": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.4"
  }
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: post the contents of `components/common` please

Comment: Seconded. The problem is most likely in your `components/common.js` file.

Comment: @cssko @Pedro Castilho Unfortunately it does not seem to have anything todo with `components/common`, because I get the same error on `import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools'` and `<DevTools/>`, or `import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'`. However, if I add something like `let button = <Button></Button>` before return, then it works. I even put a breakpoint before `let button ..` is initialized and suddenly `<Button></Button>` in the return statement works.

Comment: This is my tsconfig.json: `"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "app",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }`

Comment: "jsx": "react" - not "preserve"